# How to get posts of a taxonomy in descending order Corcel Laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I'm using `Corcel` in my `Laravel` project and I have set my database connection to a `wordpress` database. I want to get the posts of a taxonomy in descending order according to post_date field. I've developed the following function but it returns the posts in ascending order. How should I change it?

```
public function posts(Taxonomy $category)
{

       return PostResource::collection($category->posts);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple available methods on the Laravel Collection :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods

Try this one :

```
return PostResource::collection($category->posts)->sortByDesc('post_date');
```

This method has the same signature as the sortBy method, but will sort the collection in the opposite order.

Comment: It worked!
So good to talk to anyone who knows.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Although your solution solved my problem, the format of response has changed. there is an integer number before every object of response!and I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: Try to add ->values->all() after the sortByDesc method